# Adding permission dynamically with Sentry in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, permissions, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

I have populated my Permissions table to hold values like "pages.add", "pages.edit" etc. While creating a group I populate those permissions in checkboxes. On submit, I iterate through posted values of those checkboxes and put them in an array. I then create the group this way:

> public function store() {
>           $validation = new CreateGroupValidator;
>
> ```
>     if ($validation->passes()) {
>         try {
>             // Create the group
>             $permissions = Input::get('permissions');
>             $pers=array();
>             foreach($permissions as $p)
>             {
>                 $pname=Permission::find($p)->name;
>                 array_add($pers,$pname,'1');
>             }
>
>             $group = Sentry::createGroup(array(
>                 'name'        => Input::get('name'),
>                 'permissions' => $pers
>             )); 
>
>             return Redirect::route('admin.groups.index');
>         } 
>         catch (\Cartalyst\Sentry\Groups\GroupExistsException $e)
>         {
>             Notification::error('A group with same name already exists.');
>         }
>     }
>
>     return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validation->errors);
> }
> ```

I see values have been populated in the array. Still sentry won't load those permission in the groups table. What's wrong? Suggestions please.

Answer (score 3):

How I use my checkboxes in the HTML looks like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="perms[page.edit]" value="1"> Allow
<input type="checkbox" name="perms[page.add]" value="1"> Allow
```

Then this is how i implemented my my update function, but both my create and update use similar code

```
$input = Input::get('perms');
$c = [];
foreach ($input as $k => $p) {
    $c[$k] = $p;
}
// Find the group using the group id
$group = Sentry::findGroupById(1);
// Update the group details
$group->name = Input::get('name');
$group->permissions = $c;
// Update the group
$group->save();
```

Hope this helps.